# Is it possible to transfer old LibreOffice user profile to the new version of LO 6.x?

Tags: libreoffice, transfer, user-profile

I like to install the new Lubuntu and need to decide which version of *LibreOffice* I shall install on that. It seem the LO 6x is different in architecture, my old user-profile is from Version: 4.4.7.2

Comment: Which "new Lubuntu" are you planning on installing? Ubuntu 16.04 and its derivatives offer LibreOffice 5.1.6 as the default. Ubuntu 18.04 and its derivatives offer LibreOffice 6.0.3 as the default. In any case, you can install more recent versions of LibreOffice if you go the ppa route or choose to install via snap packages or AppImages.

Comment: I plan to install Lubuntu 18.04. Lubuntu contains not LO but Abiword

Comment: So what exactly is your worry? Are you afraid your files created in 4.4.7.2 won't open or that macros or extensions won't work?

Comment: I just want to make shure that all the settings, arrangment of buttons, collors and further more word replacement will be resumed.

Comment: You can rearrange most buttons to where you want them, there are even custom colors. Why should word "replacement" be affected? As I suggested, do a "dry" run with an [AppImage](https://libreoffice.soluzioniopen.com/) or with a snap.

Comment: You misunderstood my question or you dont know whats all included in the user profile. It's not only a few buttons but beside the Styles and Formatting added words to the dictionary, word replacement etc. much more. It's growing over years. Really :)

Answer (score 0):

It does not work.
Normally it works by coping the 
/home/user/.config/libreoffice/ folder into the same on the new OS. But I get than an error and the program doesn’t start at all.

I'v tested then with debian 9.4 which has LO 5.2.7.2 and it works as ever, all your Styles and Formattings, added words etc. are restored.